# How to set QWidget fullscreen (but "real" fullscreen, change resolution, set modal to whole system)?

Tags: c++, qt, fullscreen, resolution, qwidget

I'm trying to make a game using Qt, cause it is so awesome ;) and you have all the stuff you need for free. The only problem is in changing system resolution and setting QWidget (or QGLWidget) "real" fullscreen.

Have any one of you managed to do something like this? How was the portability of such approach? I'd like to deploy my app on all desktop systems.

Maybe use SDL or something like SMFL to make it fullscreen?

Pls, share your hacks!

Cheers.

Comment: There is no way that I know of to change the screen resolution from within Qt library. May I ask what platform do you have and what disto in case linux?

Comment: @Neox, I'd like to change resolution cross platform, so I can develop openGL-heavy apps in Qt.

Comment: I will take a look into this, get back to you as soon as I find something

Comment: Computer says no. Qt is designed to work within the OS, not around it, which explains why there doesn't seem to be an easy way of doing this.

Comment: Probably you could use `glutInitDisplayMode` that is available in GLUT but I don't know whether Qt would like it.

Answer (score 11):

This...

```
my_widget->setWindowState(Qt::WindowFullScreen);
```

... brings your widget to a full screen resolution. Isn't that what you need?

**Edit:**
Alternatively you can call the slot [showFullScreen](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html#showFullScreen).

**Edit 2:**

1. **WIN API**

   2. [EnumDisplaySettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162611(v=VS.85).aspx)
   3. [ChangeDisplaySettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
   4. [Detailed information](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36664/Changing-Display-Settings-Programmatically)
2. **X11**

   6. I'm not familiar with this, you could ask a new question regarding how to change the screen resolution here
3. **Mac**

   8. Same as X11

Comment: Nope. This will make widget's dimensions to fill system window. I'd like to change system's resolution e.g. 800x600, then fill it with my widget and set it modal. Just like in games.

Comment: Ah sry didn't get this. You want to change the system resolution and then apply the fullscreen.

Comment: Exactly. Some time ago I found solution which use WINAPI, but I will work only with Windows obviously.

Comment: On this question http://bit.ly/x2sk3m it says that it is impossible to change the screen resolution by Qt. For Windows the Win API can do that, but I don't know about Linux, Mac, wherever else you want to deploy your application.

Comment: You could also check on which OS your application is currently running and depending on that you call the according functions (e.g. WIN API for Windows). Info about how to get the OS: http://bit.ly/Aeh2rP

Comment: thanks, this is one step forward. Now I need some snippets to change resolution and stretch QWidget whole screen. I'm upvoting your answer for that tip.

Answer (score 3):

First you have to set corresponding window flags to make your widget modal, and also get rid of the window manager frame so it will be true fullscreen

`widget->setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);`

and after that call `widget->showFullScreen();` as Exa said.

Answer (score 0):

Fullscreen:

```
topwidget->setWindowState(topwidget->windowState() ^ Qt::Window);
```